# I can't replace the sk_test key with the sk_live key on Stripe using Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I have a React Native application, running on a firebase backend. I have integrated with Stripe. The token is created by the client, and the firebase cloud function creates the charge with that token. I have built the app and tested payments using the **test** keys in Stripe.

I have now replaced the test keys with the live keys.

The live public key is working in the React Native application, and is creating a token successfully.

here is the function for creating the token code in the React Native application

```js
import Stripe from 'react-native-stripe-api';

async payByCard() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    const uid = user.uid;
    const { number, exp_month, exp_year, cvc } = this.state;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const apiKey = 'pk_live_#######################';
    const client = new Stripe(apiKey);
    try {
      const token = await client.createToken({
         number,
         exp_month,
         exp_year,
         cvc,
      });
      this.props.addToken({ token }, uid);
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error: error.message, loading: false });
    }
  }
```

The firebase cloud functions, however, is still using the secret test key.

here is the loud function for creating a charge.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

export const stripeCharge = functions.database
  .ref('/payments/{userUid}/{paymentUid}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      const payment = change.after.val();
      const userUid = context.params.userUid;
      const paymentUid = context.params.paymentUid;

      if (!payment || payment.charge || !payment.pendingBasket) return;

      return admin.database()
        .ref(`/users/${userUid}`)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
          return snapshot.val();
        })
        .then(customer => {
          const amount = Number(payment.pendingBasket.total * 100).toFixed(0)
          const idempotency_key = paymentUid;
          const source = payment.token.id;
          const currency = 'gbp';
          const description = `Athalens ${customer.address.FirstName} ${customer.address.LastName} - ${customer.address.PostCode}`
          const charge = {amount, currency, description, source};

          return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('error 1 =' + error.message);
          admin.database()
            .ref(`/payments/${userUid}/${paymentUid}/status`)
            .set(error.message)
        })
        .then(charge => {
          admin.database()
            .ref(`/payments/${userUid}/${paymentUid}/charge`)
            .set(charge)
            if (charge.status === "succeeded") {
              customerOrders(userUid, paymentUid)
              photographerUid(userUid, paymentUid)
              clearBasket(userUid)
              confirmation(userUid, paymentUid);
            } else {
              decline(userUid, paymentUid)
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('error 2 =' + error.message);
        })
    })
```

The process I am doing to upload the Secret key to firebase:

```
1. Williams-MBP:~ williamgoodhew$ cd /Users/williamgoodhew/projects/athalens/athalens_server_code/basket/functions

2. Williams-MBP:functions williamgoodhew$ firebase functions:config:set stripe.token=“sk_live_#################”

3. Williams-MBP:functions williamgoodhew$ firebase deploy --only functions
```

When I test the live payment system, a token is created, but no charge is created. and I receive the following error in the cloud functions log:

```
No such token: tok_############; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.
```

Comment: Did you hardcode the key anywhere? Are you setting the config on the correct project?

Comment: @BryanMassoth they key isn't hardcoded anywhere. I am deploying the correct project. I have tried multiple different syntaxes to make sure that the function is correct. Should the key have double quotes, single quotes or anything else surrounding it? I read somewhere that if you use the same users in test and live that it can cause errors, so I have changed users and got no success.

Comment: Could you post some code of how you are initializing Stripe and how you are creating charges?

Comment: @BryanMassoth I have updated the question with the code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I have got in contact with Firebase and it was a silly error my end.

In my cloud function, I had initialized my test key "

> const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

" instead of using "stripe.token".

I changed stripe.testkey to stripe.token.and everything worked out fine.